# Is there any way to copy folder and files to minio bucket deployed from Helm after post deployment?

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minio

I want to copy folder and its subdirectory to MinIO server which is deployed using MinIO Helm.

Is there any way to copy folder to MinIO bucket which is deployed on cloud using helm after postdeployemtn of Helm service using Helm?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a folder and its subdirectories to a MinIO server which is deployed using MinIO Helm. Use the MinIO Helm Chart to deploy the MinIO server on a cloud platform, and then use the mc command line tool to copy the folder and its subdirectories to the MinIO bucket. For example, you can use the following command to copy a folder named ‘myfolder’ and its subdirectories to the ‘mybucket’

MinIO bucket:

```
mc cp -r myfolder mybucket
```

You can also use the mc mirror command to mirror the contents of the folder to the MinIO bucket. For example:

```
mc mirror -r myfolder mybucket
```

Refer to this [MINI IO official doc](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-cp.html) for more information on this copy folder to minio